# Proper way to logout of webpages

Tags: php, session, cookies

I've been using session_destroy() for a long time to end a user's session. But after diving deep, I realized that it will only destroy the session data at the server side. The cookie will still be stored at the client's side, which means that the browser will continue sending cookies, but with session id which is no longer valid. 
So, what is the right way to log out of a session? Does one need to delete the cookie at the client side as well?

Comment: "In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that." --> http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php), there's more to do:

> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the
>   session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the
>   session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be
>   deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: it works well to destroy the session. But I can still see the cookie sent from my local server. The cookie is not getting deleted.

Comment: check again. Because it seems that code specifically sets expiry time less then current time which indeed deleted the cookie